Move Bootcamp partition within the existing disk in order to make more space available for macOS
I'm using a Macbook Pro, and I'm running Windows 10 alongside the macOS (Big Sur) in a Bootcamp partition.
As I'm running short with the free available space for osx, I need to move the Bootcamp partition within the same disk (SSD).
I've already tried clonezilla without any success. Windows won't boot.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

In case anyone has the same problem:
My only solution was the worst case scenario:

Delete Windows partition.
Resize macOS partition.
Reinstall Windows using BOOTCAMP.

